# How can you get the indices from a regular expression match?

Tags: python, regex, functional-programming

I'm looking for a more pythonic or functional programming solution to my problem.

I match a `regular expression` to a string. The regular expression captures a group around each repetition of wildcards. I use these groups to mask the wildcards in the match. An example is shown in the following code:

```
out_str_list = []
original_str = 'XYZQUACKESTARNFSDMADESBHSCHILDABCD'
match = re.search('(?=(QUACK(.{2,4})TAR(.{2,4})MAD(.{3,5})CHILD))', original_str)   # searching while grouping repetitions of wildcards
hide_ranges = tuple(match.span(i) for i in range(2, len(match.groups()) + 1))   # ((8, 10), (13, 17), (20, 25))
match_range = match.span(1) # (3, 30)
i = 0

out_str_list.append(original_str[match.span(1)[0]:hide_ranges[0][0]])
while i < len(hide_ranges):
    out_str_list.append("-({0})-".format(hide_ranges[i][1] - hide_ranges[i][0]))
    if i == 0 and len(hide_ranges) != 1:
        out_str_list.append(original_str[hide_ranges[0][1]:hide_ranges[1][0]])
    elif i == len(hide_ranges) - 1:
        pass
    else:
        out_str_list.append(original_str[hide_ranges[i][1]:hide_ranges[i+1][0]])
    i += 1
out_str_list.append(original_str[hide_ranges[i-1][1]:match.span(1)[1]])
match_str = ''.join(out_str_list)

assert match_str = 'QUACK-(2)-TAR-(4)-MAD-(5)-CHILD'
```

The code works but seems much more verbose than needed. A more general form of this example:

I have a string: `XYZQUACKESTARNFSDMADESBHSCHILDABCD`

From a regex match, I generate the tuple: `((8, 10), (13, 17), (20, 25))`

and a tuple with the starting and ending indices of the match: `(3, 30)`

How can I get a string that looks like: `QUACK-(2)-TAR-(4)-MAD-(5)-CHILD` ?

I wanted to do something similar `str.split` and `str.join({length of gap})` for each captured group. I couldn't do this exactly because I am given indices rather than a string to split on. I know that functional programming approaches would use something like map or filter, but I'm not sure how to apply a string slice in the way that I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `re.split` to extract the non-matching parts of your string, and `re.findall` to find the matching parts of your string. Then you can iterate through these sets, and aggregate the data together:

```
import re

s = 'XYZQUACKESTARNFSDMADESBHSCHILDABCD'
matches = re.findall('QUACK|TAR|MAD|CHILD',s)
non_matches = re.split('QUACK|TAR|MAD|CHILD',s)
'-'.join(["{}-({})".format(matches[i], len(non_matches[i+1])) for i in range(len(matches))])
#'QUACK-(2)-TAR-(4)-MAD-(5)-CHILD-(4)'
```

Comment: Feel free to tell me if I'm wrong because I'm not at a place where I can confirm... but this doesn't take into account the order of the matching parts, correct? That is, in this example, I require TAR to be after QUACK and before MAD

Comment: try running the code, i think it should respect the order of the matches. do you understand how the code works? `matches` is a list of the form `[match1,match2,match3, ...]`, `non_matches` is a list of the form `[nonmatch1, nonmatch2, nonmatch3 ... ]` and the last line interleaves these two lists as `match1 - len(nonmatch2), match2, len(nonmatch3) ...` (formatting them into a string as well)

Answer (score 1):

Recall that `re.sub` can take a replacement function, so you can do:

```
>>> s='XYZQUACKESTARNFSDMADESBHSCHILDABCD'
>>> def mh(m):
...     return "{}-({})-{}-({})-{}-({})-{}".format(m.group(1),len(m.group(2)),m.group(3),len(m.group(4)),m.group(5),len(m.group(6)),m.group(7))
... 
>>> re.sub(r'^.*(QUACK)(.{2,4})(TAR)(.{2,4})(MAD)(.{3,5})(CHILD).*$', mh, s)
'QUACK-(2)-TAR-(4)-MAD-(5)-CHILD'
```

You can use your regex with Python's string replace as well:

```
>>> m=re.search(r'(?=(QUACK(.{2,4})TAR(.{2,4})MAD(.{3,5})CHILD))', s)
>>> tgt=m.groups()[0]
>>> for r1, r2 in [(e, '-({})-'.format(len(e))) for e in m.groups()[1:]]:
...    tgt=tgt.replace(r1, r2, 1)
... 
>>> tgt
'QUACK-(2)-TAR-(4)-MAD-(5)-CHILD'
```